# Remove <code> tag from inline Rhtml knitr code

Tags: r, knitr

When writing Rhtml documents you can utilize `<!--rinline x -->` to write inline code in the Rhtml document. However, this code is wrapped in `<code class="inline knitr">x</code>` which can wreck havoc on basic formatting.

Is there a way to remove this entirely? So that only `x` is written into the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that only the output of what is stored in x is written into the document.  You can get this by wrapping the expression in `I()`.

Compare the differences in the output of this:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Test document</p>

<!--rinline x <- 3 -->

<!--rinline x -->

<!--rinline I(x) -->

</body>
</html>
```

This produces the following body:

```
<body>

<p>Test document</p>



<code class="knitr inline">3</code>

3

</body>
```

We can see that the first rinline gets the code tag while the second just inserts the output into the document directly.

Comment: thanks, Dason, for explaining the "[Luke, use the source](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks-html.R#L167-L169)" problem :)

Comment: Interesting, I had never even heard of `I()` before.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen This is a good read if you're working with knitr - http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/

Comment: Ack, I searched that page for RHTML not R HTML. :(